# Size of circle depends on the color?

Tags: c++, graphics, cairo

I draw a circle filled yellow (0-width border) and, on top of it, a circle filled grey (0-width border) with the same center and the same size as the yellow circle.

How come I can still see a very thin yellow boundary around my grey circle? Interestingly, if I switch the circles around (i.e. put the yellow circle on top), then the grey circle is completely hidden as it should be.

How can I make sure that the two circles are exactly the same?

Here is the drawing code:

```
cairo_push_group(cr);

cairo_set_line_width(cr, 0.0);

// The yellow circle
cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, (double)0xff/255, (double)0xfd/255, (double)0x37/255);
cairo_arc(cr, 100, 100, 10, 0, 2 * M_PI);
cairo_fill(cr);
cairo_stroke (cr);

// The grey circle
cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, (double)0x97/255, (double)0x8a/255, (double)0x84/255);
cairo_arc(cr, 100, 100, 10, 0, 2 * M_PI);
cairo_fill(cr);
cairo_stroke (cr);

cairo_pop_group_to_source(cr);
```

Comment: What colour is your background?  Anti-aliasing could be the issue here.

Comment: It's black. How do I avoid anti-aliasing issues?

Comment: Generally you don't want to (without it vector graphics can look terrible).  Not sure how you do it with Cairo.

Comment: @Robinson Yes, `cairo_set_antialias(cr, CAIRO_ANTIALIAS_NONE);` gets rid of the problem. However, edges of small circles look very rough...